# Drupal 7 entity tokens show last image in field

Tags: entities

I would like to show last image from field in metatag module via entity tokens. I am using [node:field-photo:0:file:url] This show first added image.

Do you know how show last image from field? [node:field-photo:-1:file:url] - not work

Comment: i think it should be [node:field-photo:1:file:url] instated of [node:field-photo:-1:file:url]

Comment: No for [node:field-photo:1:file:url] is shown second image. I need to display always the last. Each field may be a different number of images

Comment: Nobody knows how to display the last image?